# How can I encrypt using AES via DCT & IDCT and decrypt it back?

Tags: java, android, encryption, dct

Currently, I am working on *image encryption* and *Discrete Cosine Transform* in **Android** (Conceptually, it should work almost the same in [this paper](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/327/538/a_partial_image_encryption_method_with_pseudo_random_sequences.pdf) but with different encryption/decryption steps and without shuffling step).

**The encryption code is as follow:**

1. DCT in each 8x8 block.
2. Encrypt the DC value / low frequency value at array coordinate (0,0).
3. Convert the encrypted bytes to double arrays.
4. Save the first double array to coordinate (0,0)
5. Save the second double array to coordinate (7,7)
6. Perform IDCT.
7. Convert the resulted block from IDCT to RGBA color using `Color.rgba()` function.
8. Put it together pixels to make images.

**The decryption itself:**

1. DCT in each 8x8 block.
2. Constructing double array from coordinate (0,0) and (7,7).
3. Convert double arrays to bytes array
4. Decrypt the DC value / low frequency value from the bytes array taken after converting double arrays in step 3
5. Get the decryption bytes block arrays.
6. Convert the decrypted block to double values.
7. Save the double value to coordinate (0,0).
8. Set the coordinate (7,7) to zero.
9. Perform IDCT on 8x8 block.
10. Convert the resulted block from IDCT to RGBA color using `Color.rgba()` function.
11. Put it together pixels to make images.

..

```
// To encrypt
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, encryptAlgorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(clear);
}

// To decrypt
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, encryptAlgorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(double value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(double[] doubleArray){
    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[doubleArray.length * times];
    for(int i=0;i<doubleArray.length;i++){
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i*times, times).putDouble(doubleArray[i]);
    }
    return bytes;
}

public static double[] toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    DoubleBuffer db = bb.asDoubleBuffer();
    double[] copy = new double[db.capacity()];
    db.get(copy);
    return copy;
}

public static Bitmap applyEncryption(Bitmap image, int blockSize) throws Exception {
    int xPos = 0, yPos = 0, a = 0, b = 0;

    int _w = image.getWidth();
    int _h = image.getHeight();

    int reconstImage[][] = new int[_w][_h];
    double dctArrayGray[][] = new double[8][8];

    // It will convert image bitmap pixels to 2-D arrays
    int[][] imageData = bitmapToArray(image);

    for (int i = 0; i< (_w / blockSize); i++) {
        xPos = i * blockSize;
        for (int j = 0; j < (_h / blockSize); j++) {
            yPos = j * blockSize;

            for (a = 0; a < blockSize; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < blockSize; b++) {
                    dctArrayGray[a][b] = (double) Color.red(imageData[xPos + a][yPos + b]);
                }
            }

            DoubleDCT_2D dct = new DoubleDCT_2D(blockSize, blockSize);
            dct.forward(dctArrayGray, true);



            // Perform Encryption here....
            byte[] chiperBytes = encrypt("ThisIsASecretKey".getBytes(), toByteArray(dctArrayGray[0][0]));

            // This is the problem
            // it will overflow the minimum/maximum DCT values, since there are max/min
            //     when performing DCT

            // 1. Save the first array in coordinate (0,0)
            dctArrayGray[0][0] = toDouble(chiperBytes)[0];

            // 2. save the second array in coordinate (7,7)
            dctArrayGray[7][7] = toDouble(chiperBytes)[1];

            // This is the problem I think, it may have "bits lost", after I perform `Color.rgba()` on each block to get pixel values, after below looping. 
            // If I perform `dct.reverse` again, I will not get the same value as the `chiperBytes`
            // since it will also be decrypted (see the decryption function below this function).
            dct.inverse(dctArrayGray, true);

            for (a = 0; a < blockSize; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < blockSize; b++) {
                    int red = (int) Math.round(dctArrayGray[a][b]);
                    reconstImage[xPos+a][yPos + b] = Color.argb(0xFF, red, red, red);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // It will convert back the 2-D array to Bitmap image
    return arrayToBitmap(reconstImage);
 }


 // Decryption
public static Bitmap applyDecryption(Bitmap decryptedImage, int blockSize) throws Exception {
    int xPos = 0, yPos = 0, a = 0, b = 0;

    int _w = decryptedImage.getWidth();
    int _h = decryptedImage.getHeight();

    int reconstImage[][] = new int[_w][_h];
    double dctArrayGray[][] = new double[8][8];

    // It will convert image bitmap pixels to 2-D arrays
    int[][] imageData = bitmapToArray(decryptedImage);

    for (int i = 0; i< (_w / blockSize); i++) {
        xPos = i * blockSize;
        for (int j = 0; j < (_h / blockSize); j++) {
            yPos = j * blockSize;

            for (a = 0; a < blockSize; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < blockSize; b++) {
                    dctArrayGray[a][b] = (double) Color.red(imageData[xPos + a][yPos + b]);
                }
            }

            DoubleDCT_2D dct = new DoubleDCT_2D(blockSize, blockSize);
            dct.forward(dctArrayGray, true);


            // Perform Decryption here....

            // Get back the double values
            double[] encryptedDoubleValues = new double[2];
            encryptedDoubleValues[0] = dctArrayGray[0][0];
            encryptedDoubleValues[1] = dctArrayGray[7][7];

            // I got chiper block not completed EXCEPTION since I got bits lost during saving the encryption
            // block to image and after converting to RGBA from IDCT (Inverse DCT)
            byte[] chiperBytes = decrypt("ThisIsASecretKey".getBytes(), toByteArray(encryptedDoubleValues));

            // 1. Save the first array in coordinate (0,0)
            // This line below suppose to bring back the original value / almost the same with original
            dctArrayGray[0][0] = toDouble2(chiperBytes);

            // 2. save the second array in coordinate (7,7) and set it to zero
            // (since AC values are expected to be loss and not necessary needed)
            dctArrayGray[7][7] = 0;


            dct.inverse(dctArrayGray, true);

            for (a = 0; a < blockSize; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < blockSize; b++) {
                    int red = (int) Math.round(dctArrayGray[a][b]);
                    reconstImage[xPos+a][yPos + b] = Color.argb(0xFF, red, red, red);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // It will convert back the 2-D array to Bitmap image
    return arrayToBitmap(reconstImage);
}
```

The DCT calculation is taken from this [library](https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jtransforms/dct/DoubleDCT_2D.java).
The other functions can be taken from other question threads in stackoverflow (credits to them).

**Questions:**

1. How to store the resulted encryption / chiper result to be compatible to DCT values (since we know that DCT has max&min values)?
2. Is there a way to get my code above working? The problem lies on storing encrypted data and convert it to IDCT arrays, then get the RGBA color. The same as decryption.

Many thanks and really appreciate for the help.

*Note: I am using **Android 4.1.2 not `Java Desktop`**, so don't expect that all Java desktop compatible libraries will be available and working properly in Android.*

Comment: Just a hint then: you can use AES in CTR mode to create a stream cipher and simply follow the paper, although you would need to store the IV somewhere if you were to ever reuse the key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I ended up creating new question on how to convert byte arrays to 8bits int arrays http://stackoverflow.com/q/33201010/553060